# how to work with android media(play,pause,stop) using react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I am very new to react-native. I am having good experience on Cordova/ionic framework for Hybrid app development. I am just exploring react/react-native. One concept which I like is "virtualDOM" There are a couple of questions here. (some might be layman questions. But, just want clear my thinking.)

1. Because of VirtualDOM, do you think the memory footprint will increase?
2. I am trying to develop a small app which plays/pauses/stops a video. and starts/stops the recording of the video. Do you have any plugins available for accessing media devices?
3. Does react-native support all device native features?( **like Address Book, file system, geolocation, vibration, battery status, device native calendar, capture, contacts, device, device motion, SMS**). If so, can you point me to some links where I can access the device specific features?

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course a React Native app is slower and uses more memory than a full native app. However, React Native still seems to be pretty performant in many ways.
2. There is a library called react-native-video which supports all you're asking for. There might however be some issues on older versions of android. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video
3. A lot of these features are supported by React Native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html#content (Check APIs in the sidebar). If something is not implemented by React Native itself, probably somebody else already did and there is a npm package you can install (and link with rnpm for linking android/ios code).
   If you want something custom, you can still build your own Java/Swift/objectiveC component and wrap it to a React Native component. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html and https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html)

Comment: Thanks you verymuch.